# R how to convert double format data to datetime

Tags: r

I have a monthly dataset, from 1926 to 2020, and its date is double and the format is this:

Date

192607

192608

192609

I want to get a datatime like this:

1926-07

1926-08

1926-09

I tried `as.datatime`, however, I got a wrong date, because it regard 192607 as a number reference of date.
Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. In order to format as dates you must have values for year, month and day. In your dates, there is a lack of day so you can add `01` to your date chains and format as dates:

```
#Code
df$Date2 <- as.Date(paste0(df$Date,'01'),'%Y%m%d')
df$Date3 <- format(df$Date2,'%Y-%m')
```

Output:

```
    Date      Date2   Date3
1 192607 1926-07-01 1926-07
2 192608 1926-08-01 1926-08
3 192609 1926-09-01 1926-09
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Date = 192607:192609), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ymd` from `lubridate` with `truncated` option

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(Date2 = ymd(Date, truncated = 2), Date3 = format(Date2, '%Y-%m'))
#  Date      Date2   Date3
#1 192607 1926-07-01 1926-07
#2 192608 1926-08-01 1926-08
#3 192609 1926-09-01 1926-09
```

---

Or using `zoo`

```
format(zoo::as.yearmon(as.character(df$Date), format = "%Y%m"), '%Y-%m')
#[1] "1926-07" "1926-08" "1926-09"
```

---

We could also consider it as a string and use `regex` to convert (though it is recommended to do this in a `Date` conversion way to avoid any bugs)

```
df$Date2 <- sub("^(....)", "\\1-", df$Date)
df$Date2
#[1] "1926-07" "1926-08" "1926-09"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = 192607:192609), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have two questions, could you give me some information? 1. why should we convert to ymd at first, not convert to Y-M directly? I tried to delete Date2 and use Date3 directly, but get error `invalid 'trim' argument`. 2. Could you explain more about c(NA, -3L)? Thanks.

Comment: @ling YOu don't need to create a new column.  It can be just `df <- df %>% mutate(Date2 = format(ymd(Date, truncated = 2), "%Y-%m"))`.  It is just to make things clear..  Regarding why should we convert to `Date`.  not necessary, but it is often a good practise to convert to `Date` object to avoid any bugs.  It can be done directly as well

Comment: @ling I added a direct approach with `sub` from `base R`

Comment: Understand. Thank you for your help!